# spring security issue while integrating word press with spring web application

Tags: java, wordpress, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

we have web application implemented using spring & hibernate frameworks, we used spring-security for handling user authentication, we developed a blog using word press, and blog is running on XAMP and web application is running on tomcat server. I am throwing login-modal in blog for accessing my web application. I am authenticating user using ajax-call & in spring-security CSRF is enabled. But here I am unable to generate CSRF in wordpress, what is the best way to generate CSRF in wordpress java script file ?. Because without CSRF spring-security throwing an errorPage. Any help will be appreciated.